# how can i fix visual-studio-code c++ linker command failed error

Tags: c++, compilation, apple-m1

I'm using m1 air mac.
I made 1012.cpp file in "0x09" folder. But I mistyped "cpp" as "Cpp". There was a problem when I compiled this with vscode.

here error message:

```
cd "/Users/7bella/Desktop/sourcecode/vscode_c/barkingDog/0x09/"
 && clang++ -std=c++17 1012.Cpp -o 1012 && "/Users/7bella/Desktop/sourcecode/vscode_c/barkin
gDog/0x09/"1012
ld: warning: ignoring file 1012.Cpp, building for macOS-arm64 but attempting to link with file built for unknown-unsupported file format ( 0x23 0x69 0x6E 0x63 0x6C 0x75 0x64 0x65 0x20 0x3C 0x62 0x69 0x74 0x73 0x2F 0x73 )
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I changed file name to 1012.cpp but still same error.
The error message says, file name is 1012.Cpp even though I changed file name to 1012.cpp

If I change the file name to ex) 1012_1.cpp or change folder name to ex) 0x0A, the error doesn't occur.
how to fix this problem while keeping the file name 1012.cpp
please help me

if i change the file name to 1012_1.cpp, it works correctly.
[image]

here is my task.json file:

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: clang++ 활성 파일 빌드",
            "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
            "args": [
                "-std=c++17",
                "-fcolor-diagnostics",
                "-fansi-escape-codes",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "detail": "컴파일러: /usr/bin/clang++"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think it's a problem because the file generated when file name incorrectly written as 1012.Cpp is still left.
Is there a way to delete the file?

Comment: Case sensitive filesystem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be that the file extension hasn't been updated properly.

Try this command:
`mv 1012.Cpp 1012.cpp`

Comment: I tried this but got the same error...

Comment: You can try to use the find and replace feature `(shortcut: Command + Shift + H)` to find and replace all occurrences of ".Cpp" with ".cpp"

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I can't find any ".Cpp". there is only "1012.cpp"

Comment: Try to clean the build directory before compiling the program again. 
`rm -f 1012
rm -rf 1012.dSYM`

Comment: if I compile and execute with terminal like this:
"clang++ -std=c++17 -o 1012 1012.cpp"
"1012"
it works correctly

but i use control+option+N (Run code) same error occur

Comment: is that the problem of extension (Code Runner)?

Comment: Oh I fixed it. After disabling the code runner extension, reloading the vscode, enabling the code runner again "Run code" works well. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful if you share the task.json, anyways, take a look at the file and check if your command option looks similar to this: `"command": "/usr/bin/clang++"`
Here you have an example task.json file:

```
  "tasks": [
{
    "type": "shell",
    "label": "clang++ build active file",
    "command": "/usr/bin/clang++",
    "args": [
        "-g",
        "${fileDirname}/*.cpp",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}"
    ],
```